# PHP/Libcurl - Unable to fetch images with relative paths using ../..

Tags: php, libcurl

I have a PHP script that's using libcurl and is having a hard time downloading files that are using certain types of relative paths.

For example:

```
http://www.msn.com/../../i/09/4ebdf19a1ce03cce12e11926256422.gif
```

I'm using the following curlopts:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: could you be a bit more precise? what happens unexpectedly? or what did you expect to happen but does not? And did you notice PHP knows true/false? :)

Comment: Yes I'm aware that true/false works.  It downloads a 4k image that can't be opened but if you visit the URL via your browser it's a working image that's not 4k.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

This tells CURL to include the HTTP headers in what curl_exec returns. So you'll have a bunch of http "garbage" in front of the .gif data, corrupting it.

Comment: Even if I remove that it still won't expand that relative path and get the file.

Comment: curl doesn't know anything about paths. it'll just fire that url off in the request exactly as you provided it. Have you tried opening that 'bad' 4k file in a text editor to see if it's really corrupted .gif data, or has some error text?

Comment: Oh ok so it has to be an issue with the URL that's being passed in then?

Comment: perhaps msn has issues with you using curl to (obviously) scrape content and is serving up something other than a .gif image. Look at the contents of the 'bad' file with a text editor.

Comment: I'm sending the Chrome UA though so it shouldn't be an issue.  I'll examine the contents of the image.  Good suggestion.